# getting an error on my if statement and i cannot figure out why

Tags: c

this is the error that i am getting....am i missing something? i have tried to move braces around but it still does not like the else statement

91 syntax error before "else"

```
void admin_signIn(struct profile *puser)
{
     int i=0;
     char input[20];
     strncpy( puser->UserName, "password", strlen("admin")+1 );     
     strncpy( puser->Pwd, "password", strlen("password")+1 );
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
     printf("Enter admin user name:");
     fgets(input,10,stdin);
     rewind(stdin);    
     printf("Enter admin password:");
     fgets(input,10,stdin);
     rewind(stdin);

     if(strcmp(puser->UserName,input) && strcmp(puser->Pwd,input));
      {
        printf("the user name is good");
      }
        admin_menu(puser);
    else
      {
      printf("try again");
      }
}
```

Comment: If you get a message about `else`, why not check the line just _above_ the `else`? Oh, and you are missing a `}` to end the loop.

Comment: Why won't you move admin_menu(puser);
 to the end?

Comment: `wd,input));` removing the semicolon will get you somewhere.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvotes. Even though this is a trivial (you might even say stupid) beginner problem, it is a valid and real problem for the OP. It "shows research effort and is clear" enough that at least it does not deserve downvoting. C'mon guys, just because you gathered enough rep to be able to downvote, you don't need to be rude to newbies...

Answer (score 5):

```
 if(strcmp(puser->UserName,input) && strcmp(puser->Pwd,input));
                                                              ^---here
```

That semicolon terminates the if(), and then you've just got a dangling `{` on the next line. Without an active `if()`, the `else` is not permitted.

Comment: omg duh....sorry about that, i have been looking at this to long

Comment: does that if statement look right to you guys, like it will work i am trying to compare what the user inputs to what is already stored

Answer (score 2):

There is an admin_menu(puser); before else

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strcmp(puser->UserName,input) && strcmp(puser->Pwd,input))
```

You asked if this is a correct if statement. I'd say it doesn't do what you want.
strcmp() returns 0 when the two arguments match. Also, you are comparing two different variables to the same input string.

You might want to re-write this to something of this form:

```
if(!strcmp(puser->UserName,input_Username) && !strcmp(puser->Pwd,input_Password))
{
    /* good login */
}
else
{
    /* failed login */
}
```

When you are having the usser input the data, be sure to use two seperate variables to store the password and user name so you can do the test in one if() statement.

[See strcmp()](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#strcmp)